# display columns from different tables during data bind

Tags: asp.net, mysql, data-binding, gridview

How to bind data from two tables.

tbl_user
first name userid

tbl_usermessage
userid  timereceived msgid

How to display username and timereceived in datagrid

```
SELECT TimeReceived, FirstName FROM tbl_usermessage INNER JOIN tbl_user on tbl_usermessage.tbl_user_UserID = tbl_user.UserID WHERE tbl_message_MsgID = @Value1";
```

This is what I am trying i am getting syntax error.  here Time received is from  tbl_usermessage and firstname is from tbl_User and both table has userid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect a SqlDataSource to your DataGrid by setting the SqlDataSource's DataSourceID property to the SqlDataSourceID. Set the SqlDataSource's SelectCommand property to the SQL required to get the items:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT tableone.username, tableone.userid, tabletwo.userid, tabletwo.timereceived
FROM tableone INNER JOIN tabletwo ON tableone.userid=tabletwo.userid"
```

And also set the ConnectionString property:

```
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDatabaseConnectionString %>" >
```

Comment: SELECT TimeReceived, FirstName FROM tbl_usermessage INNER JOIN tbl_user on tbl_usermessage.tbl_user_UserID = tbl_user.UserID WHERE tbl_message_MsgID = @Value1";    This is what I am trying i am getting syntax error.  here Time received is from  tbl_usermessage and firstname is from tbl_User and both table has userid

Answer (score 1):

How about joining both tables on your sql query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the data from your database with a SQL Query which JOINs the two tables on a column that is common to both:

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT
    userId, username, timereceived
FROM
    Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.userId = Table2.UserID
```

Here's [an example](http://bit.ly/pXC5kM) for your reference.